# Difference between api call '/me' and '/<fbid>'

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As the title says, what is the difference when doing a request with the php sdk, between api('/me') and api('/current_user_fbid')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Dhiraj Bodicherla said, "me" and "current_user_id" are the same - but there are exceptions when you cannot use "me" - for example, when you do requests using application or page tokens. So if you are writing a backend code which is dealing with multiple users/tokens etc - keep this in mind - **you can't use "me" with app token.**

Answer (score 1):

Adding to `avs099's` answer.

You cannot use `me` without an access token. But you can use an `id` without access token.

e.g.

http://graph.facebook.com/1137725463 works, but
http://graph.facebook.com/me will fail

Answer (score 0):

Using `me` or `current_user_id` in graph api will yield the same result.

You should check **[Developer Tool Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)**

**[DEMO](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/1cd4cd7ad778478e02021363efba6e54)**

Hope this helps